# UIView & UICollectionView. scroll issue

Tags: swift, uikit

I can't understand how this preview is implemented.
[image]

If I add a UIView and a UICollectionView, but the UIView has a fixed position and scrolling only appears for UICollectionView

I use the UIView as a UICollectionCell, then scrolling will be for the entire screen

Comment: It might be a section header view in the collection view and configured to be "sticky" so it doesn't scroll upwards.

Comment: Even if the header is pinned at the top, the scrolling would be at the top of the collection. This collection has horizontal scrolling and can be swiped to scroll.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you mean by “the scrolling would be at the top of the collection” and this is the first time you have mentioned horizontal scrolling. You should look into collection view compositional layouts.

Comment: If you look at the screenshot above, you will see a scroll that is on the same level as the UICollectionView. My knowledge of composite layout is not very good, but I think the problem is still elsewhere, so the question arises, what should I do with NSLayoutConstrait?

Comment: The cell with the UIView will take up 40%, and the cell with the horizontal scroll will take up the remaining screen space, because if we look at how the Instagram profile page is made, we will see two scrolls - horizontal and vertical.

Comment: @MarkRoberts - it's not entirely clear what your goal is, but since you mention *"Instagram profile page"* you might want to take a look at this article (not mine): [Building Instagram profile screen with Compositional Layout](https://nemecek.be/blog/72/building-instagram-profile-screen-with-compositional-layout)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I hope it will help me.

Comment: @DonMag Great example, but the implementation is different - the layout changes on click. If we look at the Instagram profile page, we can see a slightly different logic that is bothering me.

Comment: @DonMag My goal is to implement a collection with scrolling [instagarm-followers](https://github.com/mdo91/instagarm-followers) like this. But I also need the scrolling to be applied to a UIView, and in this example, the followers & following are fixed.

Comment: @MarkRoberts - ok, then I have no idea what you're trying to do (never a good idea to say *"like this other app"* because then we have to install that app and try to guess what you're referring to). In the image you posted in your question -- you say *"UIView has a fixed position and scrolling only appears for UICollectionView. If I use the UIView as a UICollectionCell, then scrolling will be for the entire screen"*. But you don't want either? Try to do a better job of explaining what your goal is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.